# Escaping HTML entities and UTF-8 in Python

Tags: python, character-encoding

I am working on the parsing of a HTML file containing many special characters (in both Unicode and HTML entities forms).
Despite having read a lot of documentation on Unicode with Python, I still cannot convert HTML entities properly.

Here is the test I ran:

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> p = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
>>> s = p.unescape("&#139;")
>>> repr(s)
"u'\\x8b'"
>>> print s 
Â‹ # !!!
>>> s
u'\x8b'
>>> print s.encode("latin1")
‹ # OK, it prints fine in latin1, but I need UTF-8 ...
>>> print s.encode("utf8")
Â‹ # !!!

>>> import codecs
>>> out = codecs.open("out8.txt", encoding="utf8", mode="w")
>>> out.write(s)
# Viewing the file as ANSI gives me Â‹ # !!!
# Viewing the file as UTF8 gives NOTHING, as if the file were empty # !!!
```

**What is the correct way of writing the unescaped string s to a UTF8 file ?**

Comment: Are you at a command prompt in Windows, by chance?

Comment: You would only see the correct output of the UTF-8 encoded print if your interactive session there where itself running on an utf-8 terminal. And it is not, because if it where, the print encoded as `latin1` would have failed instead.

Comment: To anwer the question about the encoding of my session, the output of the `locale` command confirms that it is UTF-8. (I am under Linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U+008B is a control character, therefore seeing nothing is not unusual. "‹" is U+2039 SINGLE LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK, and is not even in Latin-1. It *is*, however, character 0x8B in **CP1252**. And stop relying on the Windows console output to tell you what's correct or not, unless you run `chcp 65001` beforehand.

Comment: I use a Linux console over SSH. From your explanation, I can infer that there is a bug in the `unescape()` function, that returns U+008B instead of U+2039. Am i wrong ?

Comment: The bug is in the data. Or more specifically, whatever generated the data. It should have used `&#8249;` to encode the character, but instead selfishly assumed that the world revolves around Microsoft and used a character that [doesn't exist in the proper specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html).

Comment: Nice link, I had not found the full list of HTML entities. You are right, the data is violating the specs. Running my test with &#8249; gives the expected result.